# Excel Copy Paste Button

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, copy-paste

I have an Excel sheet with over 200 rows. I want a button on each row that when clicked with copy the value of the row over to a second sheet.

Below is what I am looking for. However I cannot update the macro for over 200 buttons.

Is there anyway to make each button relative to the row it is sitting on?

```
   Rows("6:6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("6:6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: One way to do this is to put your code in the worksheet's on_selection_change event handler. The code does need to pay attention to the currently selected cell or row in order to function correctly.

Comment: [Avoiding the use of Activate and Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) will also help

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure to have the buttons within the cell, you can use `Application.Caller` to determine what button was pressed, and `Shapes(btnName).TopLeftCell` to get the position of the button.
This will let you use the same macro for all the buttons.

Then you just assing those values to variables, and end up with something like

```
Dim btnName As String, btnRow As Long
btnName = Application.Caller
btnRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(btnName).TopLeftCell.Row
ActiveSheet.Rows(btnRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(btnRow)
```

This will copy everything, including the button itself to `"Sheet1"`.
If you only want the values, you can use `PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues`.

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(btnRow).Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(btnRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

Or setting the values.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(btnRow).Value = ActiveSheet.Rows(btnRow).Value
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! I added "Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete" so that the rows copied over would go to the top of Sheet 1 as they were copying to the same row as the original sheet.